# OSGI: generate bundle-classpath in maven-bundle-plugin

Tags: maven-2, osgi, bundle, war, pom.xml

I am trying to add all the jars from web-inf/lib into the Bundle-ClassPath.
I saw several ways to do it, none of them is working:

1) add

```
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
<Embed-Directory>WEB-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
<Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
```

2) add

```
<Bundle-ClassPath>.,{maven-dependencies},WEB-INF/classes</Bundle-ClassPath>
```

Of course, writing jars one-by-one in "Bundle-ClassPath" solves the problem, but it doesn't sound like a reasonable solution.

thanks

Comment: I know this is an old post, however I though it's worth adding that the second option you present above must be used in conjuction with the first, ie. the {maven-dependencies} variable can only be used after you have specified the embed dependencies, and is used to control the position of the embedded dependencies in the Bundle-ClassPath

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your first code snippet, wouldn't using `<Embed-Dependency>` as you have it written work?  The examples at http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html seem to indicate it would.

Also, what version of the bnd plugin are you using?  These features are available as of 1.2.0+.

Comment: the first option started to work when I wrote 
<Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>

Answer (score 1):

Working example for a classic webapp being OSGified

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <instructions>
                                <Private-Package>org.example</Private-Package>
                                <Web-ContextPath>webappcontextpath</Web-ContextPath>
                                <Bundle-ClassPath>.,WEB-INF/classes,{maven-dependencies}</Bundle-ClassPath>
                                <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                                <Embed-Directory>WEB-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                            </instructions>
                            <supportedProjectTypes>
                                <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                            </supportedProjectTypes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that `Embed-Dependency` is inside the `instructions` element